# Android: "Path for project must have only one segment"

Tags: android

I just setup the NotePad sample project as described here, but when I try to launch it (Ctrl+F11) I received the following error message box:

> Path for project must have only one
>   segment.

[image]

What does this error mean and why is it happening?

(I tried to consult [this article](http://dushi.co.uk/09/07/2009/error-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment/), but it seems irrelevant to my problem because I have no getProject anywhere in this copied-verbatim sample project)

Comment: I got this as a result of renaming a project.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem: It turns out that when I specified the (only) Launch configuration for the project (Properties > Run/Debug Settings), I forgot to specify the Project name:

[image]

Hmmm... I thought that if I right-click the project, its name will be taken automatically.

Anyway, it works now. Yeah! :)

Comment: +1 I had the same problem: I did fill in the 'name' field, but not the "project name" field. THanks for this :)

Comment: Really looks like a bug in Eclipse or Android SDK

Comment: Yup, we must specify the project which we will run. If we build JAVA app we can just run it but for android we must do this.

Comment: You deserve lots of points for saving everyone time. Thank you!

Comment: Good Job, it would probably taken me many hours of my life to find out this little thing :)

Comment: My project from my package explorer isn't showing up in the name list in the screenshot (helpful screenshot btw)

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same problem and resolved it in the following steps:

1. Expand the *src* directory
2. Expand *com.example.Login* (the app name)
3. Right click on *MainActivity.java*
4. Go to run as-> run configurations
5. Browse your project
6. Launch Default activity
7. Run

`note:` Before doing this, set an AVD by using Android virtual device manager.

Comment: great. I faced the same problem and resolved using the above steps thanks.!! I als0 voted up for you.

Answer (score 7):

For me it was helpful to do the following:
Run -> Run Configurations -> Select Android Application
I don't know why, but there was something called New Application...delete it....after delete everything should work fine

Comment: for me it was called "new configuration"

Answer (score 5):

i have the same problem i solved it below

go to properties> run/debug settings and erase your current settings and run it

it should work

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project -> Properties > Run/Debug Settings --> Select your project and click on Edit --> look for the "Project:" and write your project name there.

Comment: Tnx Amit it worked for me , and thoose whoose project name already is there in the list select your project and again select OK . then try to debug it will work. Same as it worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The project line, not the name line, was left blank after copying in a renamed project to eclipse. Another time, it was the name line. I love eclipse.