# How to execute Eclipse project on Mac?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made Android project, it works for me and sent it for my customer. He has Macintosh (I developed it for Windows). When he tries to execute my project after importing the following error appears:

> Launching New_configuration. Path for project must have only one
>   segment.

The project's folder is "\project". Running *Project* -> *Clean* does nothing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This question and answer seems to be having similar problem like yours. See if it helps
[Android: "Path for project must have only one segment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961151/android-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment)

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should export the project and import it **proprely** in the new computer.

You should have encrypion problems too (Eclipse use another system than utf8 :-/ )

Comment: Encryption problems? Not UTF-8? Not sure what you're talking about--there shouldn't be any problems like that at all.

Comment: so much the better for utf8 but on my mac it's sort of Apple encoding and it's broke my éàè ;-)

Comment: I think @clement meant _encoding_ problems, not encryption

Comment: sorry... indeed, encoding ;-)