# How do I solve this error I get in eclipse during android development?

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: “Path for project must have only one segment”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961151/android-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment)

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
>   Path for project must have only one segment.

What is this error and how do I solve it?

I get it when I try to debug or run the program.
I am not able to do anything as the program does not go any further.

Comment: your entire question title, though verbose, could be expressed with the "android" tag alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix Launch configuration for the project (Properties > Run/Debug Settings) and specify your Project name [image]