# pydev Google App run Path for project must have only one segment

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I had trouble to run the pyDev Google App run on Eclipse. I can't create a new run configuration and I get this error message: Path for project must have only one segment.
Any ideas about how to fix it? I am running Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: However this is an android related question, it answers your question, too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961151/android-path-for-project-must-have-only-one-segment

Comment: The solution in your post is unhelpful for this particular case.

Comment: The android solution is not helpful for my question. Any ideas?

Comment: This error went away for me after upgrading to PyDev 3.9. Now Eclipse crashes when I try to debug my project, but that's a whole different problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is clearly a bug, but there's a possible workaround: In a .py file in your project, right-click and go to "Run As."  Then, select "Python Run" (not a custom configuration).  Let it run and crash or whatever this particular module does.  Now, go look at your run configurations - you'll see one for this run.  You can customize it as if you had made it anew.